# Making sure a quiz doesn't ask the same thing twice

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a python quiz that asks 25 questions. I've used a dictionary to hold the questions, with a key. I've used the random.randint() function to select a random question from the dictionary, and my aim is to, once the question has been answered, remove the question from the dictionary so that it can't be answered again. I haven't coded the logic that decides whether the answer is correct or not. Here is the code that matters:

```
def delete_question():

    try:
        del questions[chosen_question]
    except KeyError:
        pass
    question_number -= 1
    random_question.update()
    root_win2()



def root_win2():
    global questions, chosen_question, random_question, question_number

    question_number = 0

    questions = {
        1: "Describe what the instruction 'BRP' does.",
        2: "Describe what is meant by the term 'Open Source Software'.",
        3: "What is meant by the term 'Lossy Compression'?",
        4: "What is the number '55' as an 8-bit unsigned integer?",
        5: "What might a printer use RAM for?",
        6: "Describe the term 'firewall'.",
        7: "Describe the Rapid Application Development process."



}

    question_number = 7

    If question_number > 0:

        chosen_question = random.randint(1, question_number)



        random_question = Label(root, bg="white", text=(questions      [chosen_question]), font = ('Courier', 13))
        random_question.place(x=10, y=50)


        delete_button = Button(text="Next", command=delete_question, height=3, width=12)  
        delete_button.place(x=370, y = 420)
```

How should I edit my code so that when the question is asked, it isn't asked again?

Here's the full code if anyone needs it:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import random

def destroy():

    random_question = Label()

    close_button.destroy()
    about_button.destroy()
    start_button.destroy()
    version.destroy()
    conf.destroy()
    root.title("Computer Science Quiz")
    random_question.destroy()
    root_win2()


def delete_question():
    question_number = 0
    try:
        del questions[chosen_question]
    except KeyError:
        pass
    question_number -= 1
    random_question.update()
    root_win2()



def root_win2():
    global questions, chosen_question, random_question, question_number

    question_number = 0

    questions = {
        1: "Describe what the instruction 'BRP' does.",
        2: "Describe what is meant by the term 'Open Source Software'.",
        3: "What is meant by the term 'Lossy Compression'?",
        4: "What is the number '55' as an 8-bit unsigned integer?",
        5: "What might a printer use RAM for?",
        6: "Describe the term 'firewall'.",
        7: "Describe the Rapid Application Development process."

}

    question_number = 7

    if question_number > 0:

        chosen_question = random.randint(1, question_number)


        random_question = Label(root, bg="white", text=(questions[chosen_question]), font = ('Courier', 13))
        random_question.place(x=10, y=50)


        delete_button = Button(text="Next", command=delete_question, height=3, width=12)  
        delete_button.place(x=370, y = 420)



def root_win1():
    global root, close_button, about_button, start_button, version, root

    root = Tk()
    root.title("Start Menu")
    root.geometry("800x800")
    root.configure(background='white')
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

    close_button = Button(text="Quit", fg="red", command=quit, height=3, width=12)  
    close_button.place(x=370, y = 420)

    about_button = Button(text="About", fg="blue", command=new_win, height=3, width=12) 
    about_button.place(x=370, y=360)

    start_button = Button(text="Begin", fg="green", command=confirmation, height=3, width=12)
    start_button.place(x=370, y=300)

    version = Label(root, bg="white", text="v0.48")
    version.place(x=767, y=0)




def callback(event):
    webbrowser.open_new(r"http://www.ocr.org.uk/Images/170845-specification-accredited-as-level-gce-computer-science-h046.pdf")



def new_win(): 

    about = Toplevel()
    about.title("About")
    about.geometry("370x300")
    about.configure(background='white')
    about.resizable(width=False, height=False)

    about_text = Label(about, bg="white", anchor=W, justify=LEFT, text = "OCR AS Level Computer Science Quiz \n\n"
                                                         "This app quizzes you on 25 random questions related to computing, \n"
                                                         "in accordance with the OCR AS Computer Science specification \n\n"
                                                         "You are given 10 minutes to answer 25 questions \n\n"
                                                         "Version 0.48 \n\n"
                                                         "Firas Hafiz - 2018 \n\n"
                                                         "You can visit the subject specification from the link below: \n")

    about_text.pack()

    back_button1 = Button(about, text="Understood", command=about.destroy, height=2, width=10)
    back_button1.place(x=145, y=240)

    link = Label(about, bg="white", justify=LEFT, anchor=W, text="OCR AS Level Computer Science Specification", fg="blue", cursor="hand2")
    link.pack()
    link.bind("<Button-1>", callback)

    about.focus_set()
    about.grab_set()

about.mainloop()


def confirmation():
    global conf

    conf = Toplevel()
    conf.title("Begin?")
    conf.geometry("250x100")
   conf.configure(background='white')
    conf.resizable(width=False, height=False)

    conf_label = Label(conf, bg="white", justify=LEFT, anchor=W, text="Are you sure you want to continue?")
    conf_label.pack()

    continue_button = Button(conf, text="Continue", command=destroy, height=2, width=10)
    continue_button.place(x=30, y=30)

    back_button2 = Button(conf, text="Go back", command=conf.destroy, height=2, width=10)
    back_button2.place(x=136, y=30)

    conf.focus_set()
    conf.grab_set()


    conf.mainloop()








root_win1()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [mcve] instead of dumping all of your code? Also, please just ask a single question in a question; your tkinter question is completely unrelated, and can’t be answered with the same answer, so it should be posted separately. (You can always copy the “share” links and paste them into the other question, to explain that they’re separate questions but for the same code, so the other one might be relevant to anyone reading.)

Comment: Anyway, what’s the problem here? It looks like your `delete_question` function should delete the question. I’m not sure why it’s doing some of the other stuff, like creating a local named `question_number` that it sets to 0 and then to -1 and never looks at, but that shouldn’t break anything.

Comment: Finally: Wouldn’t it be a lot simpler to just `random.shuffle` the questions, and then just ask the questions in (shuffled) order, without bothering with trying to delete anything?

Comment: It's not deleting the question, I can't pinpoint what's wrong, but when I run it, it keeps asking the questions as if they were still there.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking two completely different questions. This is wrong in this site. You should make two separate questions instead.

You can remove the question from the dictionary using del

```
del questions[chosen_question]
```

You also don't need to keep the number of questions yourself, as you can always use the `len()` function in dictionaries:

```
len(questions)
```

To generate a random question, independent of what numbers are still in the dict, you could use `random.choice` instead of `randint`:

```
chosen_question = random.choice(questions)
```

And for your label, you need a StringVar to edit it. Create the label once

```
v = StringVar()
random_question = Label(root, bg="white", 
     textvariable=v, font=('Courier', 13))
```

Then you can set the text anytime you want

```
v.set(questions[chosen_question])
```